# How to get the nickname for my Android device set in Google Play Store

Tags: android, api, google-play

I got multiple devices of the same model. So in Google Play Store, I would see them with the same name which by default is the Carrier + Manufacturer + Model. So it is quite confusing which one is which. I recently found out that you can set a nick name for each device under "My order and settings" -> Settings on Google Play Store website. It is great. But anyone know if there is a way to retrieve the nick names of the current device on Android in my app? I would like to display the nick name rather than the model number in my app. I guess if there is a way, it must be through an API provided by Google Play Store app? Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no official Google Play Store API, so this can't be done. There is one unoffical one tough, but you can't do this with this one eather.

Comment: Thanks, Ahmad! Could you please point me to the unofficial API?

Comment: Here you go: http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/
But as said this does not support getting the nickname.

Answer (score 0):

The validated answer is pretty much outdated.

You can get the player's informations from Google Play Games Service using the [PlayerClient class](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/PlayersClient). Once you get it, you need to load the player's information and then you will get the [Player class](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Player). Then you can create some custom function to get user details

```
  public JSONObject get_user_details() {
    JSONObject userDetails = new JSONObject();

    // Needs to be loaded before, it is the Player class mentioned before
    if (currentPlayer != null) {
      try {
        userDetails.put("playergame:name", currentPlayer.getDisplayName());
        userDetails.put("playergame:photo_uri", currentPlayer.getIconImageUri());
        userDetails.put("playergame:uid", currentPlayer.getPlayerId());
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to load player's game informations: " + e);
      }
    }

    return userDetails;
  }
```

If you are looking for a better example, google has published [samples code on github](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/35d283fd365a1bdb290cc43b4bfc46ec09c7220b/TypeANumber/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/tanc/MainActivity.java#L507).

Comment: Are you sure that this returns the nick set in the play store console?

Comment: @Ahmad Yes Im. I implemented this solution in a modules for Godot Engine: https://github.com/xsellier/godotandroid/blob/master/android/src/google/GooglePlayer.java